# Powershell | Error in Do Until Loop with Counter

Tags: loops, powershell

Why cant I have a counter in a do until loop like this?
I don't understand the error.
Is there any correlation with the $table ?

I also tried renaming the variable $row, nothing changed.

```
            $row = [int]1
    do {    #Create a row
            $r = $Table.NewRow()
            #Enter data in the row
            $r.HostName   = $Sheet4.Cells.Item($row,2).Text
            $r.RecordType = $Sheet4.Cells.Item($row,3).Text
            $r.TimeStamp  = $Sheet4.Cells.Item($row,4).Text
            $r.TimeToLive = $Sheet4.Cells.Item($row,5).Text
            $r.RecordData = $Sheet4.Cells.Item($row,6).Text
            $r.Preference = $Sheet4.Cells.Item($row,7).Text  
            #Add the row to the table
            $Table.Rows.Add($r)
            $row++                
       } until (!$Sheet4.Cless.Item($row,2))
```

Errorcode:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Script\SCRIPT.ps1:392 char:17
+                 $row++
+                 ~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Table creation data:

```
    $TabName = "ExcelRecords"
    #Create Table object
    $Table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable “$ExcelRecords”
    #Define Columns
    $Col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn ZoneName,([string])
    $Col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn HostName,([string])
    $Col3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn RecordType,([string])
    $Col4 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn TimeStamp,([string])
    $Col5 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn TimeToLive,([string])
    $Col6 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn RecordData,([string])
    $Col7 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Preference,([string])
    #Add the Columns
    $Table.columns.add($Col1)
    $Table.columns.add($Col2)
    $Table.columns.add($Col3)
    $Table.columns.add($Col4)
    $Table.columns.add($Col5)
    $Table.columns.add($Col6)
    $Table.columns.add($Col7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you have a typo in your script:

change the line

```
} until (!$Sheet4.Cless.Item($row,2))
```

to:

```
} until (!$Sheet4.Cells.Item($row,2))
```

This would explain the Null reference exception. Because I can't remember that a worksheet has a property of `Cless`

Comment: Guess I'm the incorporation of stupidity! Thanks a lot! After hundreds of lines, I missed the tree for all the woods.

Comment: Before answering I was honestly trying to mistype `Cells` to be sure this is it, instead of just checking my subversion for old code to confirm.

Comment: Hab gerade gesehen, dass du ja Deutsch sprichst ;). Danke nochmal. Grüße!

Comment: Yes I do, but SO is an English site, so we should stick to our manners.

Comment: Ofc, I would never ask a question in german. I just thought it to be an amusing coincidence.